# IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, index-error

I'm trying to run this code

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""Script for investigating the different carbon sinks function for 1 unit emission"""

start_year=1                # Model Start Date
end_year=100000              # End date
dt=1                        # Incremented time
time=[start_year,end_year,dt] # Time variable
N=len(time)              # Number of increments 

E=1

tauC=50
tauC_fat=[30,300,10000]


C=np.zeros((1,N))            # CO2 Concentration
C_fat=np.zeros((1,N))
C0=0
C[1]=C0
C_fat[1]=C0


dC=np.zeros((1,N-1))
dC_fat=np.zeros((1,N-1))

fraction=[0.5,0.3,0.2]
dC_frac=np.zeros((1,len(fraction)))
dC_memory=np.zeros((1,len(fraction)))

for n in range (1,N-1):

        if n>1:

            E=0
        dC[n]=(E-C[n]/tauC)*dt

        for m in range(1,3):

                dC_frac[m]=fraction[m]*E-dC_memory[m]/(tauC_fat[m])
                dC_memory[m]=dC_memory[m]+dC_frac[m]*dt
                dC_fat[n]=dC_fat[n]+dC_frac[m]*dt


        C[n+1]=C[n]+dC[n]
        C_fat[n+1]=C_fat[n]+dC_fat[n]

plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.ylabel('ppmv')
plt.title('Fig 5')
plt.legend('Original Model', 'Adapted Model')`
```

As I want to plot these different models against each other, but I keep getting the error message C[1]=C0

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1.

I'm pretty new to python, and I cant really see whats wrong with defining the variable C[1] to be zero in this case? Would I need to create an array for this to run? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do when you set `C[1]=C0`? Since you ran `C=np.zeros((1,N))`, you've already got an np array full of zeroes.

Comment: `C=np.zeros((1,N)) ` creates an array of one element.  Since arrays index from zero, `C[0]` is valid, but `C[1]` is out of bounds.

Comment: I'm trying to set the values for the first few runs as in the loop c(n) is a changing variable. Do you think I should get rid of the zero arrays?

Comment: Since `C` is created as a 2d array, the problem assignment is implicitly `C[1,:]=0`.  That is you are trying to assign 0 to the 2nd row of `C`. Pay close attention to the wording of that error message.  Why are you starting with shapes like (1,N) instead of (N,)?  And remember that Python indexing starts with 0, not 1.